# OpenGL, blending transparent textures with object color

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I can set my fragment shader to showing colors of the object or the texture color of the object. My question is, how can I combine those two so that I can have a transparrent picture with lines for bricks, and then show the different colors underneath, so that by changing the color of the object, you change the color of the bricks.

I tried using mix() for that in the fragment shader, but it only shows me the glClearColor where it is transparent insteath of the red color I have assigned it!

My fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

varying vec3 shared_colors;
varying vec2 shared_texCoords;

void main() {
    vec4 color = vec4(shared_colors, 1);
    vec4 texture = texture2D(diffuse, shared_texCoords);
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb, texture.rgb, 1), 1);

    gl_FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

EDIT: Added texture loader func:

```
void Texture::createTexture(SDL_Surface *rawImage, GLenum format) {
    //Convert to a texture of pure color pixels for OpenGL
    SDL_Surface *image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, rawImage->w, rawImage->h, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_BlitSurface(rawImage, NULL, image, NULL);

    //Generate texture
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);

    //Tell OpenGL to use this texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

    //Set texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    //Generate texture from image
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, image->w, image->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    m_dimension = new PixelSize(image->w, image->h);

    //Free loaded images
    SDL_FreeSurface(rawImage);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}
```

Comment: You should not use **4** for the internal format. In older versions of OpenGL this was allowed (and it meant to pick any format with 4 components), but the proper thing to use is really `GL_RGBA` or better yet, `GL_RGBA8`. Your shader is GLSL 1.20, so your implementation may not support `GL_RGBA8` but it will definitely understand `GL_RGBA`.

Comment: Well, it didn't change my situation. They both ran perfectly, but nothing different happened.

Comment: I didn't think it would change anything to be honest. But the spec. does not allow using the number of components anymore, so at least your code is more portable now :P I believe the masks you are passing to `SDL_CreateRGBSurface (...)` are to blame for your constant alpha value. On a little-endian machine (e.g. x86), I think you need an alpha mask (last parameter) of **0xff000000**. For all other color channels, you can use a mask of **0**, but alpha needs an explicit mask.

Comment: I managed to find the problem! I did actually need the masks for the RGB components. I used 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff

Answer (score 2):

#### You should take a closer look at [`mix (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mix.xhtml) to understand why using **1** for **`a`** effectively does nothing meaningful (*it returns y*).

Let us start by considering the usual alpha blending function: `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`.

This means to take the alpha channel of the source and multiply it by the source color (*fragment color*) and add that to the inverse of the alpha channel multiplied by the destination color (*framebuffer*).

**AlphaBlend** = **Src**<sub>RGBA</sub> * **Src**<sub>A</sub> + **Dst**<sub>RGBA</sub> * (**1.0** - **Src**<sub>A</sub>)

Now, if you look at the implementation of `mix (...)` it should look quite familiar:

**x** * (**1.0** - **a**) + **y** * **a**

Clearly, this is order dependent for any value of `a` != **0.5** (***1.0** - **0.5** = **0.5***) and more importantly in this case it completely throws out one of your colors if you use a value of **1.0** for `a` (as this multiplies **x** by **0.0**).

Comment: I tried using mix(color.rgb, texture.rgb, texture.a), which I assumed was right at first, but I only get a red object with no texture then. Is there somewhere else in my program I might have an missing line?

Comment: Ofc, I can't expect you to know that since you don't got the rest of the code, but do I need to set anything specific as for OpenGL attributes or run any functions to enable blending?

Comment: No, this actually is not blending strictly speaking. It does the same thing as one very specific blend function, but blending works with the output of the fragment shader and the value already in the color buffer. As for your other question, that sounds like your texture has a constant **0.0** for the alpha channel, which is interesting because textures with no alpha channel implicitly return an alpha value of **1.0**.

Comment: Sec, and Ill add my texture loader, may be some odd stuff in there =P